# iphone6+ UITableView Width issue

Tags: uitableview, iphone-6-plus

Just working on making my app support the new iPhone6+ and running into a few problems.  My Main menu depicted here is a UITableViewController; each menu item is a UITableViewCell, which has its background set as an image using the cell.backgroundView property, and text set using the cell.textLabel.text property.

I think I have my launch images setup properly; as The correct launch images are displayed; furthermore, as you can see; I've marked up my background images to verify the correct @3x resolution images are being displayed for the table background image and cell backgrounds.  When the app first loads it displays full width for a fraction of a second, then snaps into the truncated width that you see in the attached image.  This happens in the simulator and on a real device.

Any advice is much appreciated.
[image: incorrect width UITableViewController depicted in iPhone6+ simulator]

Comment: Are you using Autolayout or Autoresizing?

Comment: I'm not - thanks for the suggestion; look interesting & apparently is the 'way of the future'.  As it happens I was doing something and absolutely setting the frame width on viewDidAppear

Comment: Yes, you can have a single XIB and manage all xibs from that using autolayout or autoresizing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes,the size of scrollview in Xib you create maybe not right, I have solve the problem by changing the frame which means that I will resize the frame of scrollview while the view controller's viewWillApear: calls,the size always been set as [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size .